# Find the latest file name in a tree using Ruby Find

Tags: ruby, timestamp, depth-first-search

I have a very large tree. I want to search for the last modified file, with a specific base file name.
I.e., there are many files with the same basename, and I just want the last modified. I  want to find (efficiently), the last modified
I.e., Recourse directories, depth first, then, by modify date (latest first). I could not find anything using Find.find how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
Dir.glob('path/**/*')                # all files below `path/`
   .select { |f| File.file?(f) }     # exclude folders
   .max_by { |f| File.mtime(f) }     # pick file by maximum modification date
```